# Failed to resolve dependencies - org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2

Tags: eclipse, grails, dependency-management

Trying to run the hello world grails app.

I'm getting this error:

```
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.g
roovy for more information):

- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
```

How do I resolve this dependency?

Edit: I am running this on Windows CMD

Comment: Trying to run from Eclipse? Can you try simple `grails run-app` from command prompt. If application runs this will at least isolate the issue to only eclipse related. A Hello World Grails app would never be depend on eclipse in anyways. :)

Comment: I am running it from Windows Command Prompt

Answer (score 2):

That jar is available at Maven Central - make sure that you have the `mavenCentral()` (and optionally `mavenLocal()`) repo uncommented in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
   ...
   grailsPlugins()
   grailsHome()
   grailsCentral()
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: If you cannot reach `mavenCentral` then you have to add the jar to app 's `lib` which is a bad idea, I think. Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: I think so. I can only find directions for: groovy -DproxyHost=10.x.x.x -DproxyPort=8080 myscript.groovy.. I think I need to add username and password

When running grape install org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder I get 'Your proxy requires authentication.'

Comment: This was definitely a proxy issue. I'm out from behind the proxy and now everything works

Comment: Adding Maven's repo (mavenLocal and mavenCentral) solved the problem for me. Maybe only one of them is needed.

Comment: On a second reading of stacktrace in my case, the problem was "module not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler#ecj;3.7.2", not "Failed to resolve dependencies" as the question contains.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command

```
grails -DproxyHost=<proxyhost> -DproxyPort=8080 run-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the maven website and download the ecj-3.7.2.jar and save it to springsource\grails-2.2.3\lib\org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler\ecj\jars